# glColor3f Setting colour

Tags: c++, opengl

This draws a white vertical line from 640 to 768 at x512:

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
      glColor3f((double)R/255,(double)G/255,(double)B/255);
      glVertex3f(SX, -SPosY, 0); // origin of the line
      glVertex3f(SX, -EPosY, 0); // ending point of the line
glEnd();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

This works, but after having a problem where it wouldn't draw it white (Or to any colour passed) I discovered that disabling GL_TEXTURE_2D Before drawing the line, and the re-enabling it afterwards for other things, fixed it. I want to know, is this a normal step a programmer might take? Or is it highly inefficient? I don't want to be causing any slow downs due to a mistake =)

Thanks

Comment: Are you binding a texture somewhere else in your code? Maybe the texture isn't being unbound, and then gets applied to the lines.

Comment: Yep I am! Thanks. I was actually binding it in the Sprite Create function I had. Does this mean I should bind it, draw the textured quad and then unbind it? Then ofcourse the Line function should work =)

Oh and yep that fixed it:
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL);

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is extremely common. A major problem a lot of people face is an unbound texture being applied to a line accidentally, or having GL_TEXTURE_2D enabled, but without a texture, in which case the line is always drawn black (no texture = black = 0, (black(0) * given color = black(0))

There is nothing inefficient as such with your code, though it is usually a wise choice to try to avoid switching unnecessarily. (eg. if you were to have to draw another line as well, don't constantly enable/disable, instead do it all in between one disable and enable).

Hope this helped.